# Non numeric argument to mathematical function Deriv

Tags: r

```
sqrt(Deriv(x^2,"x"))
```

> $ non numeric arguments to mathematical function.

How to solve it?

Comment: Are you trying to use R to do symbolic algebra? Because that's not what R specializes in like Maple or Mathematica. It's more of a numerical computation tool. What package does `Deriv` come from, because it's not a base R function.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the `Deriv` function from the `Deriv` package, then passing the argument as a string should work for the first part:

```r
library(Deriv)
Deriv("x^2","x")
## [1] "2 * x"
```

(but, guessing by the error message you report above, you've already done that ...)

Getting the square root will be harder. **If** you have `rSymPy` installed (which requires Python and the `sympy` Python library as well) then this works:

```r
library(rSymPy)
sympy("var('x')")
sympy("sqrt(diff(x**2, x))")
## [1] "2**(1/2)*x**(1/2)"
```

---

As @MrFlick says, you won't be able to do much symbolic computation in R, unless you use an R interface to a computer algebra system (e.g. [Ryacas](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Ryacas)). You could use Maple, Mathematica, or open-source alternatives like [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/) (for Python) or [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org).

In R, you can use `D()`:

```
(dd <- D(expression(x^2),"x"))
## 2 * x
```

- you need to wrap the expression to be differentiated in `expression()`
- R won't be able to subsequently take the square root

You can (rather clumsily) evaluate the square root of this expression numerically ...

```
eval(substitute(sqrt(y),list(y=dd)),list(x=4))
```